# Listview two items per row vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, listview

I'm using vb.net 3.5 and making the UI in VB forms.

I intend to upgrade our tech but in the meantime, how would I display two items per row using a Listview?

In other words, I **don't** want two columns for one item:

```
Item id   Item value
--------------------
Item 1    Value 1
Item 2    Value 2
```

But really two items spanning two columns:

```
Item 1     Item 3
Item 2     Item 4
```

Thanks

Comment: Each ListViewItem displays as its own row, and each sub item as its own column, so it sounds like you **don't** want the ListView.  You could put each in its own group to get close to what you want

Answer (score 1):

If your items has subitems, you can only show the subitems with `ListView.View` set to `View.Details` which will always use one row for each item. Otherwise you can use one of the other `ListView.View` options. Here is an example using `View.Tile` that sizes the tiles so that two will fit in a row.

```
Dim lv As New ListView
lv.Location = New Point(10, 100) 'Pick a location and size that will fit in your form
lv.Size = New Size(100, 100)
lv.View = View.Tile
lv.TileSize = New Size(45, 20)
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("Item 1"))
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("Item 2"))
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("Item 3"))
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("Item 4"))
Me.Controls.Add(lv)
```

Obviously, you could use the forms designer to create the ListView. I have created it in code here so that all the information is in one place.